# Jquery problem with .addClass and .removeClass methods

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu on a page and can't get `jQuery` to do the job. The code will be self-explanatory.

So I have a class that's called `.dead` which is basically `display: none;` in css, `.header-main` which is one div, and `.header-main-menu` which is what needs to pop up when I press the button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var trigger = $('a.header-main'),
    var mainstuff = $('.header-main'),
    var menustuff = $('.header-main-menu');

    function buttonSwitch() {
        mainstuff.addClass('.dead');
        menustuff.removeClass('.dead');
        trigger.click(function () {
            buttonSwitch();
        });
    }
});
```

When I click the button nothing's happening. I'm new to jQuery so thanks for taking your time to help. :)

Comment: While the code you've presented is self-explanatory, you haven't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

When you use `addClass()` or `removeClass()` (or `toggleClass()`) you don't need the dot in name. Just use the class name.

```
mainstuff.addClass('dead');
menustuff.removeClass('dead');
```

Also when you select elements, decide if you want to end every line or chain selections. If you chain them, don't use `var` again.

This is valid:

```
var trigger = $('a.header-main'),
mainstuff = $('.header-main'),
menustuff = $('.header-main-menu');
```

This is also valid:

```
var trigger = $('a.header-main');
var mainstuff = $('.header-main');
var menustuff = $('.header-main-menu');
```

According to your HTML your trigger selector doesn't match anything, so you have to fix that ie `$('.main-button > a')`.
And use codepen or something if you want to show html, css and js at the same time.

Comment: There is several problems with your code.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: Still not working, here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyQWPe

Comment: Move the click event outside the function.
`function buttonSwitch() {
        mainstuff.addClass('dead');
        menustuff.removeClass('dead');
    }

    trigger.click(function () {
        buttonSwitch();
    });`